# Any reason to NOT install both bootloader and Ubuntu to external HDD?

Tags: grub2, external-hdd

I currently have a dual boot arrangement on my primary (internal) HDD which includes Win7 and Ubuntu. I've also procured a 500 GB external USB HDD and was thinking of installing one or more distros on it.

- Would it behoove me to also install Grub to the external drive and
  then use my boot order option at machine startup to select the
  external HDD at a time of my choosing?
- It seems like adding multiple distros to a single bootloader on the
  internal drive could have some disadvantages should my internal drive
  fail?
- I suppose a usb stick drive would still be an option as a bailout
  plan but a fully operational and bootable install would seem even
  better. Is this sound logic or are there disadvantages to that plan I
  haven't considered?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt sound logic to me because the whole point of grub is to load different OS from a drive at boot up.

If you have an external drive just make it bootable. I don't see how could grub be useful.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm misunderstanding the concept but what happens then if my internal drive fails? If If my only bootloader resides on the internal drive, wouldn't that scenario render my external drive unbootable then? It NEEDS a working bootloader right? And if that working bootloader is no longer accessible because of my primary drive failing, it seems like it'd be a bad sitaution.

Comment: I think you are missing the point, Grub is not a recovery tool. It is meant to let you choose between multiple OS for a given drive. If the internal fails. you can change the booting order in your BIOS to put the external in the first order.I am not saying there are disadvantages Im trying to point out that it is not necessary.